# In pySimpleGUI, how can you enable a button that was itself enabled by clicking another button?

Tags: pysimplegui, event-loop

I'm trying to build a simple workflow using pySimpleGUI. The workflow is very simple, consisting of 5 sequential steps (no branching). My concept is to display a series of buttons, one to activate each task in the workflow, all but the first disabled. That way, the user *sees* the complete workflow, and is obliged to execute it in a predetermined order. When you click the first button, the second is enabled; when you click the second button, the third is enabled and so on.

My minimum code is:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
button_size = 15
layout = [
    [sg.Button('Begin >>')],
    [sg.Button('Generate regions', key='A', disabled=True, enable_events=True, size=button_size)],
    [sg.Button('Apply to image', key='B', enable_events = False, disabled=True, size=button_size)],
]

window = sg.Window( title='Name', layout=layout)


# Event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'Begin >>':
        window['A'].update(disabled=False)
        
    if event == 'Generate regions':
        window['B'].update(disabled=False)
        

window.close()
```

The problem is that when you click the first button, although the second button *appears* to be enabled, in fact it's not; when you click the second button, nothing happens.

Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: There's no event `'Generate regions'`, but `'A'` which is the key of that Button.

Comment: `event` will be the `Buttons`'s `key` when clicked.  If no `key` is specified on a `Button` then the text will be the `key`. Change your if statement to be `if event == 'A':` and `== 'B'`

Comment: Thanks Jason and Mike - problem solved. What fooled me was that in the case of the `submit` method ```if event == 'Submit' ``` works. Maybe because the submit method automatically assigns the name to be the same as the label?